# Which states do not recognize or have not designated a special day of observance for Juneteenth Independence Day?

Tags: united-states, us-state-laws

Which states do not recognize or have not designated a special day of observance for [Juneteenth Independence Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juneteenth)?

Comment: I was not one of the VtC'ers, as I do not have the rep to do so, however here is my educated guess: trivia. The Wikipedia answers the question and you do not discuss how it does not for you. It is only after reading the answer that I can only guess it is because of the discrepancy of 45 of 50 and only 4 states remaining, but you _do not state that is why you are questioning Wikipedia_ and therefore _as written_, your question is trivia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining the Wikipedia article's [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Juneteenth&action=history&year=2018&month=6&tagfilter=), New Hampshire is the forty-sixth state to observe Juneteenth day.  However, no one has edited the article to change the "45 of 50" to "46 of 50" states.  They did [remove New Hampshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Juneteenth&diff=846619573&oldid=846611832) from the list of states that do not recognize it, with a [citation](https://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/apxnew-hampshire-governor-recognizes-juneteenth-day/) to support that claim.

The remaining four states are listed in the Wikipedia article as

> Hawaii, Montana, North Dakota and South Dakota

Their citation is unreadable for me due to the way that they use Javascript (yes, I know there are workarounds, but I dislike supporting broken pages).  I was able to confirm that New Hampshire was the forty-sixth state to recognize Juneteenth day at [seacoastonline.com](http://www.seacoastonline.com/news/20180619/juneteenth-historically-proclaimed-in-new-hampshire):

> The council recommended New Hampshire join 45 other states in recognizing Juneteenth.